# Delete Data in SQL Server using multi-threads?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a huge table (log) which keeps some history data. It has more than 10 columns:

```
Id, Year, Month, Day, data1, data2, data3, ......
```

Because the table is huge, it has lots of indexes and some FK on it.

The system keeps inserting lots of new data (based on date) into this table. The table grows quickly. Currently, we use a windows service to do batch delete old data. Here is what we are doing now.

```
SET @TotalRows = 0;
SET @Rows = 0;

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM vwTop2K

    SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT

    IF(@Rows < @BatchSize)
    BEGIN
        BREAK;
    END

    SET @TotalRows = @TotalRows + @Rows

    IF(@TotalRows >= @DeleteSize)
    BEGIN
        BREAK;
    END

    SET @Rows = 0;
END
```

`vwTop2K` is a view which gets top 2000 old rows from the table.

It works fine, but gradually, we realize that this process can not delete data fast enough. Since the table is huge, we can not drop indexes then rebuild it when delete. Since the table is not partitioned, we can not use partition, and it is not practical to rebuild the table with partition for the existing data.

So, at the end, we think using multiple threads. The system is coded by C#. The idea is: we have, say 10 threads, each thread call the stored procedure to do the batch delete for a different day, so threads will not mixed together.

Is this the correct way to do this? Or, really will not help much since they all try to delete data in the same huge table although the data is for different date in different thread? Is it worth the effort?

Thanks

More information:

1. yes, the database is huge, about 4 TB. This table is about 1TB. I forget the # of rows, but about more than 1 billion rows
2. simple recovery model
3. each delete, delete 2000 rows or 5000 rows, so it will generate huge log file. In each batch delete, at most delete 200K rows

Comment: your T-log must be huge due to constant inserts and deletes as well. Are you guys keep that in check?

Comment: Can you define huge?  Are we talking hundreds of thousands?  Millions?  Billions of records?  What recovery model are you using?  What percentage of data are you retaining in the batched delete?  I see no conditions, so are you deleting ALL data?  If so, you can just truncate.  We need more info!

Comment: added more info in the question.

Comment: And in any case adding more threads may not help.  If your current limitation is IO or blocking, adding more workers won’t help.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

You could always use transaction isolation levels to enable code to run in parallel. It may be that one of your requests is blocking the others, which gives the impression of the code being slow. In reality, removing millions of rows doesn't take long unless you are doing complex queries such as LIKE or CONTAINS

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017